# Ques significa el parametro 'boundary' en las peticiones http post

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cabeceras-http

Estoy desarrollando una app en ios que manda imagenes a un servidor desde swift.

Al hacer el body de la peticion `POSt` tengo que indicarle varias veces el parámetro `boundary`. Que siginifica este parámetro??

Os dejo un ejemplo de mi código:

```
let body = NSMutableData()
let mimetype = "image/jpg"
let nombreImagen = self.obtenerNombreImagen()

body.appendData("--\(self.generateBoundaryString())\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"param_uno\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData("\(self.parametro_uno)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData("--\(self.generateBoundaryString())\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"param_dos\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData("\(self.parametro_dos)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData("--\(self.generateBoundaryString())\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey)\"; filename=\"\(nombreImagen)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
body.appendData(imageDataKey)

body.appendData("\r\n--\(self.generateBoundaryString())--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `boundary` sirve para separar los parámetros. Ejemplo:

En una petición http post normal, los parámetros que envias son:

```
name = John
age = 12
```

Y se envían con este formato: `name=John&age=12`

Pues bien, al usar una petición http post con esta cabecera: `multipart/form-data`, el boundary seria similar a usar `&`

```
--XXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

John
--XXX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="age"

12
--XXX--
```

Esta respuesta la he sacado de [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)